# How to test for nil or empty condition in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What is the cleanest way to select from the database? (active is boolean, name is string)

```
:active => true
:name not nil
:name not empty string
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where('active = true AND name != '' AND name IS NOT NULL')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
where(['active = ? AND name != ? AND name IS NOT NULL', true, :name])
```

Frequently in rails this is being done from params and that makes this a little safer and so is a better practice.